# Concatenar achivos CSV por columas comunes sin usar PANDAS

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de concatenar dos archivos csv en base a columas comunes. Por ejemplo, un archivo csv de empleados donde tiene una columna con código de departamento (y otras columnas más). Otro archivo de departamentos donde se tiene una columa con un códido de departamento (y otras columnas más).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores de la tabla de **empleados** son:

```
cod_departamento,Lugar_nacimiento,Nombre
12,Barcelona,Juan
14,Paris,Alberto
12,Catalunya,Pedro
11,Catalunya,Maria
11,Barcelona,Jose
```

Los valores de la tabla de **departamentos** son:

```
cod_departamento,Departamento
11,Finanzas
12,Ventas
13,Administración
14,Marketing
```

Yo estoy tratando de unir los archivos en base a estas columnas comunes y obtener un nuevo archivo txt donde tenga la COMBINACIÓN de las dos tablas. No se debe usar pandas. Mi código es:

```py
dat = []
x = 'C:/Users/Zona Info/Downloads/Data/volcano.csv'
with open(x, newline = '') as File_1:  
    reader_1= csv.reader(File_1, delimiter = ',', quotechar='|')
    for row_1 in reader_1:
        print(row)
    # importando el segundo fichero
        y = 'C:/Users/Zona Info/Downloads/Data/eruptions.csv'
        with open(y, newline = '') as File_2:  
        reader_2= csv.reader(File_2, delimiter = ',', quotechar='|')
            for row_2 in reader_2:
             print(row)
             for row_1 in row:
                 if row_1 == row_2:
                    dat.append(row_1, row_2)
```

Disculpad pero he llegado hasta ahí y no logro conseguir concatenar en un nuevo archivo. Agradezco vuestros valiosos conocimientos y aportes!

Comment: Debes proporcionar un ejemplo de los archivos de entrada y del archivo de salida deseado.

Comment: ya actualice una foto

Comment: Una foto no son datos. Copia y pega al menos los valores como texto en la pregunta. Si no nos ayudas a ayudarte...

Comment: Te faltó la salida

Answer (score 0):

Una opción puede ser convirtiendo los departamentos en un diccionario, donde la llave será `cod_departamento` (el elemento 0) y el valor, los demás campos:

```py
with open('ruta/de/departamentos.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
    depart = {x[0]:x[1:] for x in reader}
```

Hasta aqui `depart` tendrá el formato:

```
{
  'cod_departamento': ['Departamento'], 
  '11': ['Finanzas'], 
  '12': ['Ventas'],
  ...
}
```

Ahora se lee el otro archivo y cada fila se concatena con `departamento[cod_departamento]`

```py
dat = []
with open('ruta/de/empleados.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
    for empl in reader:
        dat.append([*empl, *depart[empl[0]]])
```

Si se hace un `print(dat)` se obtiene:

```
[
    ['cod_departamento', 'Lugar_nacimiento', 'Nombre', 'Departamento'], 
    ['12', 'Barcelona', 'Juan', 'Ventas'], 
    ['14', 'Paris', 'Alberto', 'Marketing'], 
    ...
]
```

No mencionas el orden de las columnas en la salida, pero si quieres cambiarlo, tendrás que especificarlas manualmente:

```py
        dat.append([empl[0], depart[empl[0]][0], empl[1], empl[2]])
```